# Deactivate jenkins job while other is running

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to block a certain jenkins job while another one is running as some sort of condition?

I would like job "A" to be disabled while job "B" is running, and once job "B" is done, then job "A" should be available again.

I have read that it is possible to block upstream jobs when the jobs are part of a flow and the flow is running, but I would like to know if it s possible for 2 completely independent jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) to do this.

You're going to want to:

1. create a category for the two jobs in the Jenkins global
   configuration.
2. In each build check the Throttle Concurrent Builds
   option.
3. Choose Throttle this project as part of one or more
   categories.
4. Set Maximum Total Concurrent Builds (and Maximum
   Concurrent Builds per Node if applicable) to 1
5. Check the category box to mark the job as part of the category.

This will limit either job from running while the other one runs, so if Job A is running then B won't start, and if Job B is running than A won't start.

Answer (score 2):

Use this [Build Blocker](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) Jenkins Plugin.

You can block A in job B's config. As long as 'A' is running, 'B' would not run.

You can block Both A & B in B's config, thus B would run only no other As or Bs are running.

Additionally, You can block B in A's config, they will block each other.

*job names are case sensitivity